# filtering pattern in a file using sed or grep

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I'd like to store all the unique usernames present in the `extended.log` file into a new file using the commands `awk`, `grep`, and/or `sed`.

The following are the field-names in my file, separated  by tabs. and I just want the values of the `"username"` field (the 12th field).

```
"record_id"     "client_id"     "request_id"    "date_time"     "elapsed_time"  "status"        "size"  "upload"        "download"      "bypassed"      "client_ip"     "username"      "method"        "url"   "http_referer"  "useragent"     "mime"  "filter_name"   "filtering_reason"      "interface"     "cachecode"     "peercode"      "peer"  "request_host"  "request_tld"   "referer_host"  "referer_tld"   "range" "time_profiles" "user_groups"   "request_profiles"      "application_signatures"        "categories"    "response_profiles"     "upload_content_types"  "download_content_types"        "profiles"
```

The following is a sample of the contents of the file:

```
"SVZerDLJhIj6G3PA.6575.1466420105.346.1837.1"   "1837"  "1"     "20/Jun/2016:16:25:05"  "4"     "200"   "0"     "-"     "0"     "-"     "192.168.12.13" "anonymous@192.168.12.13""GET"   "-"     "-"     "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows 98; Win 9x 4.90)"   "-"     "-"     "-"     "192.168.14.11:8080"    "TCP_MISS"      "DIRECT"        "safesquid"      "192.168.14.11:8080"    "-"     "-"     "-"     "0"     ""      "NO_AUTHENTICATION"     ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      ""
"SVZerDLJhIj6G3PA.6575.1466420107.357.1838.1"   "1838"  "1"     "20/Jun/2016:16:25:07"  "4"     "200"   "0"     "-"     "0"     "-"     "192.168.12.13" "anonymous@192.168.12.13""GET"   "-"     "-"     "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows 98; Win 9x 4.90)"   "-"     "-"     "-"     "192.168.14.11:8080"    "TCP_MISS"      "DIRECT"        "safesquid"      "192.168.14.11:8080"    "-"     "-"     "-"     "0"     ""      "NO_AUTHENTICATION"     ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      ""
"SVZerDLJhIj6G3PA.6575.1466420109.367.1840.1"   "1840"  "1"     "20/Jun/2016:16:25:09"  "4"     "200"   "0"     "-"     "0"     "-"     "192.168.12.13" "anonymous@192.168.12.13""GET"   "-"     "-"     "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows 98; Win 9x 4.90)"   "-"     "-"     "-"     "192.168.14.11:8080"    "TCP_MISS"      "DIRECT"        "safesquid"      "192.168.14.11:8080"    "-"     "-"     "-"     "0"     ""      "NO_AUTHENTICATION"     ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      ""
"SVZerDLJhIj6G3PA.6575.1466420111.377.1841.1"   "1841"  "1"     "20/Jun/2016:16:25:11"  "4"     "200"   "0"     "-"     "0"     "-"     "192.168.12.13" "anonymous@192.168.12.13""GET"   "-"     "-"     "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows 98; Win 9x 4.90)"   "-"     "-"     "-"     "192.168.14.11:8080"    "TCP_MISS"      "DIRECT"        "safesquid"      "192.168.14.11:8080"    "-"     "-"     "-"     "0"     ""      "NO_AUTHENTICATION"     ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      ""
"SVZerDLJhIj6G3PA.6575.1466420113.387.1842.1"   "1842"  "1"     "20/Jun/2016:16:25:13"  "5"     "200"   "0"     "-"     "0"     "-"     "192.168.12.13" "anonymous@192.168.12.13""GET"   "-"     "-"     "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows 98; Win 9x 4.90)"   "-"     "-"     "-"     "192.168.14.11:8080"    "TCP_MISS"      "DIRECT"        "safesquid"      "192.168.14.11:8080"    "-"     "-"     "-"     "0"     ""      "NO_AUTHENTICATION"     ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      ""
"SVZerDLJhIj6G3PA.6575.1466420115.399.1843.1"   "1843"  "1"     "20/Jun/2016:16:25:15"  "5"     "200"   "0"     "-"     "0"     "-"     "192.168.12.13" "anonymous@192.168.12.13""GET"   "-"     "-"     "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows 98; Win 9x 4.90)"   "-"     "-"     "-"     "192.168.14.11:8080"    "TCP_MISS"      "DIRECT"        "safesquid"      "192.168.14.11:8080"    "-"     "-"     "-"     "0"     ""      "NO_AUTHENTICATION"     ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      ""
"SVZerDLJhIj6G3PA.6575.1466420117.410.1844.1"   "1844"  "1"     "20/Jun/2016:16:25:17"  "4"     "200"   "0"     "-"     "0"     "-"     "192.168.12.13" "anonymous@192.168.12.13""GET"   "-"     "-"     "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows 98; Win 9x 4.90)"   "-"     "-"     "-"     "192.168.14.11:8080"    "TCP_MISS"      "DIRECT"        "safesquid"      "192.168.14.11:8080"    "-"     "-"     "-"     "0"     ""      "NO_AUTHENTICATION"     ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      ""
"SVZerDLJhIj6G3PA.6575.1466420119.421.1845.1"   "1845"  "1"     "20/Jun/2016:16:25:19"  "4"     "200"   "0"     "-"     "0"     "-"     "192.168.12.13" "anonymous@192.168.12.13""GET"   "-"     "-"     "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows 98; Win 9x 4.90)"   "-"     "-"     "-"     "192.168.14.11:8080"    "TCP_MISS"      "DIRECT"        "safesquid"      "192.168.14.11:8080"    "-"     "-"     "-"     "0"     ""      "NO_AUTHENTICATION"     ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      ""
"SVZerDLJhIj6G3PA.6575.1466420121.431.1846.1"   "1846"  "1"     "20/Jun/2016:16:25:21"  "4"     "200"   "0"     "-"     "0"     "-"     "192.168.12.13" "anonymous@192.168.12.13""GET"   "-"     "-"     "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows 98; Win 9x 4.90)"   "-"     "-"     "-"     "192.168.14.11:8080"    "TCP_MISS"      "DIRECT"        "safesquid"      "192.168.14.11:8080"    "-"     "-"     "-"     "0"     ""      "NO_AUTHENTICATION"     ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      ""
"SVZerDLJhIj6G3PA.6575.1466420123.445.1847.1"   "1847"  "1"     "20/Jun/2016:16:25:23"  "4"     "200"   "0"     "-"     "0"     "-"     "192.168.12.13" "anonymous@192.168.12.13""GET"   "-"     "-"     "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows 98; Win 9x 4.90)"   "-"     "-"     "-"     "192.168.14.11:8080"    "TCP_MISS"      "DIRECT"        "safesquid"      "192.168.14.11:8080"    "-"     "-"     "-"     "0"     ""      "NO_AUTHENTICATION"     ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      ""
"SVZerDLJhIj6G3PA.6575.1466420108.240.1839.1"   "1839"  "1"     "20/Jun/2016:16:25:23"  "15623" "200"   "2826"  "0"     "2826"  "-"     "192.168.0.14"  "anonymous@192.168.0.14""CONNECT"        "connect://livehelp.safesquid.com:443/" "-"     "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"    "-"     "-"     "-"     "192.168.14.11:8080"    "TCP_MISS"      "DIRECT"        "livehelp.safesquid.com"        "livehelp.safesquid.com"        "safesquid.com" "-"     "-"      "1K-10K"        ""      "NO_AUTHENTICATION"     "uncachable request,BUSINESS SITES REQ" ""      "computersandsoftware"  ""      ""      ""      "uncachable"
```

Comment: welcome to U&L. can you show us a sample of log file ? as is, it is impossible to answer the question. Please, edit your post, do not add sample as a comment.

Comment: `awk '{print $12}' | sort | uniq`

Comment: @geisshirt yeah it worked. and how can I do the same using sed and grep commands..?

Comment: instead of `sort` and `uniq`?

Comment: I mean i need sort and uniq but using grep and sed commands instead of awk :)

Comment: You want one solution for each tool? Seriously, that's a bit silly. "I'd like to know how to build a chair using a hammer, with a saw and then with a screwdriver"

Comment: Instead I'd like to know how to build a chair using wood,plastic and iron :)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 sed -e 's/^.*"\([^" ]*\)"".*/\1/' log | sort | uniq

 egrep -o  '[^"]+@[^"]+' log | sort | uniq
```

where

- `-o` print only matched pattern
- `[^X]+` any number (> 0) of char different from `X`

please note

- sed solution relays on a typo/feature in your file (double double quote)
- grep solution relays on foo@some.where pattern
- awk (or perl for that matter) is better suited to extract n-th field.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` on the tab-delimited file:

```
awk -F '\t' '{ print $12 }' file
```

This would extract the 12th field.  Redirect the output to a new file if you want to.

To remove the flanking double quotes from the data, you may use

```
awk -F '\t' '{ sub("^\"", "", $12); sub("\"$", "", $12); print $12 }' file
```

This performs two substitution to remove the first and last characters of the 12th field (if they are double quotes) before printing it.

To skip the first line, in case it's a header line:

```
awk -F '\t' 'FNR > 1 { sub("^\"", "", $12); sub("\"$", "", $12); print $12 }' file
```

To only get unique usernames, using only `awk`:

```
awk -F '\t' 'FNR > 1 && !( $12 in seen ) { seen[$12]++; sub("^\"", "", $12); sub("\"$", "", $12); print $12 }' file
```

This uses an array keyed on the 12th field to keep track of what usernames have already been seen.  If the data in the 12th field is not a key in the array, then it has not been seen.

An alternative way is to just test on `!seen[$12]` instead of `!( $12 in seen )`.

Using `sort` to get unique (and sorted) usernames instead:

```
awk -F '\t' 'FNR > 1 { sub("^\"", "", $12); sub("\"$", "", $12); print $12 }' file | sort -u
```